# Compatibility issue between IE6 and IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

I'm trying to implement autosuggest with the idea to get an early warning message for not allowed characters. This is in two fields, one under another. Can't increase the space in between so I should remain as is. The problem here is when I use the same code : 
          `<cfinput name="A" size="14" maxlength="5" autosuggest="O/o-is not allowed, I/i-is not allowed" value="#trim(FORM.A)#" />`
for both fields which code btw is in one of my .cmf files, the upper field auto suggest message falls under the lower field and is partially unreadable.
Tried to fix compatibility that way:

```
    <html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

it causes another problems in a table different the table I'm working in. Any ideas how to fix this!

Comment: The x-ua-compatible header was introduced in IE8; it's not supported in (or understood by) earlier versions.  Your best bet to enable whatever consistent feature support is possible between the two versions is to use the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). IE6 won't recognize it; it'll therefore, display IE6 standards mode.  It'll help a little, but you're likely going to need some old DOM L0/JavaScript techniques to pull this off in both browsers.  Unfortunately, that's the best advice I can offer based on the limited information available.  Consider updating your post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Lance, thanks for the response. Don't know what kind details to post to make it easy to answer. As I said, two work flows/tables with few required fields each. The upper one is where I like to place autosuggest feature in two different fields. When I'm using 
        `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`
 outside < head> and inside I have 
        `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`
 the upper table and autosuggest works properly, but from the lower table appear with few buttons, and the rest of the fields are not existing. In order to have them back I need to get rid of 
        `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`
. The difference only between the two tables/workflows is that the lower one have calendars in it.